# Unsure why a form is not loading onto a loaded html tag?

Tags: javascript, html, asynchronous, promise

HTML

```
<script>
let theTemplate = new template("./create-content.html");

      let promise = new Promise((resolve) => {
        theTemplate.loadTemplate("create");
        resolve("completed");
      })
      .then((resolve) =>{
        theTemplate.loadForm("goal");
      });
</script>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function template(currentPagePath){

    this.currentPagePath = currentPagePath;

    this.loadTemplate = async (pageHeading) => { 
        /* When the load is complete the resolve function is then used */
            await new Promise(resolve => $('#nav').load('./nav.html', resolve));
            await new Promise(resolve => $("#currentPage").load(this.currentPagePath, resolve));
            await new Promise(resolve => $('#footer').load('./footer.html', resolve));
            $(`#${pageHeading}`).addClass("current-page");
          };

    this.loadForm = (currentForm) => {
        $("#create-form").load(`./create-forms.html`);
    }
    };
```

The Idea, is to add the form to an element from the loaded current page. i.e.

```
await new Promise(resolve => $("#currentPage").load(this.currentPagePath, resolve));
```

I created a promise as to make sure that the currentPage was definitely loading before i then loaded the "creates-forms.html" page.

I can't seem to figure out whats going wrong

Comment: Do you see any errors on the console?

Comment: no errors appear on the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the loadTemplate function is async, I think you should await it in your promise before you resolve. So, await `theTemplate.loadTemplate("create")`; and then `resolve('completed')`

```
let promise = new Promise(async (resolve) => {
    await theTemplate.loadTemplate("create");
    resolve('completed');
    // You are not resolving your promise here.
    // It will not enter the "then" that follows.

})
```

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Hey, sorry, yeah I noticed that as well. However it still doesn't work :(

Comment: Also, since the `loadTemplate` function is `async`, I think you should `await` it in your promise before you `resolve`. So, `await theTemplate.loadTemplate("create");` and then `resolve('completed')`.

Comment: Hey, Thanks that has worked, if you comment that as a separate answer. I'll mark it as resolved thanks.

Comment: I'll just edit the current answer to reflect that :)